# JMeter overriding properties with spaces in non GUI mode with ANT

Tags: ant, jmeter, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, performance-testing

I need to pass parameter values to jmeter properties like this:

```
@echo off
cd E:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin
jmeter.bat -n 
-t E:\OMS.P01-AccountCreation.jmx 
-l E:\result.csv 
-j E:\jmeter.log 
-Jthreadgroup.count=1 
-JPRIMARY_STREET_NUMBER=1234 
-JPRIMARY_STREET_NAME=DONALDTRUMP AVENUE
```

But this will fail as the name 'DONALDTRUMP AVENUE' has an space. It will try to read 'AVENUE' as a different parameter. Is there any way to make it read as a whole value? thanks

EDIT

It works if I add "" to enclose it. However, when I try the same thing with ANT, it throws the same error. Does anyone knows how can I solve it?

EDIT 2

I tried again with command line instead of ant. I think I found the problem. I cant add too many parameters (I'm adding like 22 parameters) I'm not sure if there is a parameter limit or if there is a length limit for the whole command line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're passing properties to Ant but normally smart people don't have any problems with spaces in property values. Are you aware that:

- Ant doesn't know anything regarding `-J` command line argument
- Ant knows nothing about JMeter properties

So if you need to pass to JMeter something you can change via Ant command-line you need to do something like:

1. In *build.xml*

   ```
   <target name="jmeter">                
       <jmeter
           jmeterhome="/path/to/your/jmeter"
           testplan ="OMS.P01-AccountCreation.jmx"
           resultlog="result.jtl">        
           <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
           <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
           <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>                               
           <property name="threadgroup.count" value="${threadgroup.count}"/>
           <property name="PRIMARY_STREET_NUMBER" value="${PRIMARY_STREET_NUMBER}"/>
           <property name="JPRIMARY_STREET_NAME" value="${PRIMARY_STREET_NAME}"/>
       </jmeter>
   </target>
   ```
2. When launching JMeter test via Ant:

   ```
   ant -Dthreadgroup.count=1 -DPRIMARY_STREET_NUMBER=1234 -DPRIMARY_STREET_NAME="DONALDTRUMP AVENUE"
   ```

References:

- [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: yea, well, there is no problem this way. The main issue is the one I mentioned in Edit 2, in which I'm trying to pass 23 parameters to Jmeter. I found out it crashes when passing more than around 15 parameters in command line. So I grouped the parameter values with delimiters. However ant has an annoying bug in which "sometimes" it wont execute the jmeter script. So I just simply got rid of Ant and I'm doing its equivalent configuration in TeamCity. Although, if you have any info about that Ant bug, it would be great to know.